# Semantic music notation in HTML code

Tags: html, character-encoding

Is anyone familiar with (traditional Western) musical notation code for HTML?

I am interested in (I guess) markup code being used in a standard capacity ("work in progress" or "de facto" would be ok) in HTML or XHTML, perhaps in the web. The closer to the actual semantics, the better: that is markup alphanumeric writing of musical notes (A, B, C...) that renders in the traditional way as a stave and the musical notes and marks over it, and perhaps some lettering below in songs.

I am aware that music notation characters have already been encoded and that there is some work being done in "Music Markup Language" in XML.

But when I have inspected the code for musical scores in webpages (and even epub files), all there was in them were linked images. It would help me just inspecting the code in webpages that used a semantic approach: I have been unable to locate any. It seems a bit odd that such an old and widespread notation system has not found its way in HTML.

(I am not a musician, that is a sort of research for a relative of mine who is herself a musician.)

EDIT TO MAKE IT MORE PRECISE:
The industry standard in (Western traditional notation for) music writing and editing seem to be Finale and Sibelius. Musescore is a well known open source alternative, and all of them are compatible by adhering to Music XML.

To narrow down, I would be interested in existing software:
-usable in an HTML or XHTML environment
-that displays in good quality scalable traditional music writing
-that is standards based (to avoid proprietary software to process the code)
-that uses a code notation that is as platform-free as possible to be compatible with major (Western) music editors (eg, Music XML)

One idea would be to produce a notebook containing several musical pieces (scores) for personal use in mobile devices, that can be read and used by musicians; an individual piece should be able to be exported (through a semantic code) for sharing with others [who might be interested in making their own modifications/arrangements]. I would like it to be HTML-based to achieve total platform independence.

The best solution, I have been able to device is having the (1) Music XML code, (2) using a music editor to import it, (3) produce SVG, (4) insert the SVG within an HTML/XHTML framework. The code and the SVG require to be linked in some manner (though a db or a link within the document).

This is perhaps too specific, I would be interested in any experience or idea to accomplish tha HTML epub notebook.

Comment: What notes where you looking for in particular. I only know of &#9835; and &#9834;?

Comment: Just the notes is hardly sufficient, you need to be able to express a staccato left hand below a legato right hand in a notation which somehow makes sense to musicians.

Comment: @Enijar I was referring to the music symbols in Unicode. I cannot say whether all of those are enough or that every possible ligature is present as I have not used them personally; I have seen that many are present: from hashes to clefs to quavers to fermatae.

Comment: @Enijar If I am not mistaken in the Unicode range: 1D100–1D1FF. Though, as mentioned, that by itseld is not enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://vexflow.com/ looks nice and plays with HTML5 well, otherwise you can check out http://www.alphatab.net/

These sorts of things output images or canvas elements, not actual markup, since musical notation doesn't fit the 'block' style of HTML well.

Comment: Thank you for the prompt answer. I have spent time revising your very concise answer. This is a very good update to an equivalent question in 2010. Both recommendations are html5 compatible (thanks) and the code is not a markup language, their style resembles  Guido Music Notation (at <http://www.salieri.org/index.html>). I do not know how widespread (and well-documented) is this code style. (Please, feel free to correct me if the code behind all this are unrelated, I will appreciate it.)

Comment: Some readers have thought that the question is too broad. I will reword focusing on Music XML though I think this is a valid answer. (I have a couple of questions.)

Comment: CORRECTION for the Guido Music Notation (see: <http://www.noteserver.org/salieri/nview/embed_web.htm>). Also (1) do you think the code behind vexflow, alpahatab or Guido MN are endorsed by some standards or professional organization? (2) do you know of any reason for the javascript frameworks to be incompatible with the epub specification (by IDPF)?